# Does C# Nullable have bug in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using Nullable in Unity.

But, if I write `int? x = null`, then `x == null` will be false (which should be true).
By the way, `x.HasValue` works well.

Tested in 3 environment:
    2020.3.30f1 + Build : WebGL + ApICompatiblityLevel : .Net Standard 2.0
    2020.3.30f1 + Build : Windows + ApICompatiblityLevel : .Net Standard 2.0
    2019.4.19f1 + Build : Windows + ApICompatiblityLevel : .Net Standard 2.0

[image]

---

【Added Later】

It is not a bug from Unity. It is a problem from the Visual Studio Debugger.
In Unity, `int? x = null;print(x == null);` will result in `true`.
But in Visual Studio's Watch window, it shows `false` for `x == null`.

Comment: What are your project settings? What does your warning show in this screenshot? Where do you write your code (.NET Standard etc.)?

Comment: I added some setting info to the question.

Comment: The warning is useless. Just two CS0219, such as "The variable 'x' is assigned but its value is never used".

Comment: I did more test. Now it seems not to be a bug from Unity. It is the Visual Studio Debugger  which shows wrong information.

Comment: Does your Visual Studio show the same as me?

Comment: As mentioned in my answer, I could not reproduce it. Even the VS Debugger did show the correct behavior to me thats why I asked for further details.

Comment: Please don't add the answer to the question body. You can add and you are encouraged to write your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to reproduce this error. Unfortunately, I did not succeed, hence my written comment. I think we need some more information here.

But I found an interesting thread: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/115716/how-to-make-an-assert-isnull-test-pass-when-the-value-is-reported-as-null/115761#115761

> Here are two flavours of "null" in Unity:
>
> - Actual null
> - "Pseudo-Null" - this is a non-null Unity object (usually a GameObject
>   or **MonoBehaviour**) that has been removed from the scene using Destroy
>   or unloading a scene.

The reason this is called pseudo-null is that for an object in this state, `yourObject (in this case your int) == null` evaluates to **true** using an overloaded operator.

---

Or another possible solution could be, that Unity's `Object` defines an == operator, which will return **true** if you compare a *destroyed* instance to null, even if the reference isn't actually null. 
 So try out

```
if(x is null) { DoSomething(); }
```

or

```
if(object.ReferenceEquals(x, null)) { DoSomething(); }
```

if this solves your problem.

Comment: Thank you. I did more tests and added them to the post. Now it seems not to be a bug from Unity. The Visual Studio Debugger shows wrong result for (x==null).