# Visual Studio Debug problem: Using LitJson in Unity, If I watch a json_array by json_array[], it won't show and raise an error

Tags: json, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, litjson

[image: pic]

I'm using LitJson in Unity, debug with Visual Studio.
As shown in the picture.
I can get an item from json_array by `JsonData item0 = json_array[0];`
But if I watch `json_array[0]`, it raise an error.

This is the second time I come up with a problem where code runs right but debug runs wrong.
I don't know anything about how debug works.
Is there anything I can do or anthing I can check if "code runs right but debug runs wrong" happens again?
(The first time is [Does C# Nullable have bug in Unity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72599652/does-c-sharp-nullable-have-bug-in-unity))